# How to test React Router params with Redux and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, enzyme

**This has been resolved**

I have a component that is wrapped with `connect()` and `withRouter`. To render itself, it uses routing information in `this.props.match.params`. In my Enzyme test, the `match` prop that I pass to the `WrappedComponent` does not seem to propagate when I log the `props`. However, if I add additional props (under a different key besides `match`), they propagate fine.

The following test replicates my issue. I am fairly new to React so if anyone has tips on what I am doing wrong and what I can do to debug this, it would be greatly appreciated.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { MemoryRouter, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';


class TestComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.match;
    return (
      <div>
        { params.var1 }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TestComponent.propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.shape({
      var1: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }),
  }).isRequired,
};

const WrappedComponent = withRouter(connect()(TestComponent));

describe('WrappedComponent', () => {
  const mockStore = configureStore();
  const initialState = {};
  let store;
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore(initialState);

    const props = {
      match: {
        params: {
          roomType: 'public',
          roomName: 'test',
        },
      },
    };

    wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MemoryRouter>
          <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        </MemoryRouter>
      </Provider>,
    );
  });

  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

When I run the test, `match.params` is `{}`.

```
console.error node_modules/react/node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:33
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `match.params.roomType` is marked as required in `TestComponent`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in TestComponent (created by Connect(TestComponent))
    in Connect(TestComponent) (created by Route)
    in Route (created by withRouter(Connect(TestComponent)))
    in withRouter(Connect(TestComponent)) (at TestComponent.js:56)
    in Router (created by MemoryRouter)
    in MemoryRouter (at TestComponent.js:55)
    in Provider (created by WrapperComponent)
    in WrapperComponent

console.log src/components/__tests__/TestComponent.js:11
{ match: { path: '/', url: '/', params: {}, isExact: true },
  location:
   { pathname: '/',
     search: '',
     hash: '',
     state: undefined,
     key: '5gc3i1' },
  history:
   { length: 1,
     action: 'POP',
     location:
      { pathname: '/',
        search: '',
        hash: '',
        state: undefined,
        key: '5gc3i1' },
     index: 0,
     entries: [ [Object] ],
     createHref: [Function: createPath],
     push: [Function: push],
     replace: [Function: replace],
     go: [Function: go],
     goBack: [Function: goBack],
     goForward: [Function: goForward],
     canGo: [Function: canGo],
     block: [Function: block],
     listen: [Function: listen] },
  staticContext: undefined,
  dispatch: [Function: dispatch] }
```

---

Edit: I've gotten the test to pass by modifying it to use this:

```js
wrapper = mount(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/param1val/param2val']}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/:param1/:param2" component={WrappedTestComponent} />
      </Switch>
    </MemoryRouter>
  </Provider>,
);
```

I'll keep this open question open in case there is a recommended way to do this without the `Switch` and `Route`.

Comment: I think, it is a bad case, you should not test functionality of React Router and Redux, passing props directly to component is enough to test functionality of react component

Comment: Ok, I will try exporting just the `TestComponent` and pass in the props it needs. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slawa's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025477/how-to-test-react-router-params-with-redux-and-enzyme?noredirect=1#comment80998773_47025477) is what I ended up doing. It is not useful to test the functionality of React Router and Redux. Exporting the plain React component made the test much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to set the params directly without router

```
<Provider store={store}>
<WrappedTestComponent match={{
  params: {
    param1: param1val,
    param2: param2val
  }
}} />
</Provider>
```